# VLOOKUP return N/A, but after evaluate the formula show the correct result

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have this formula for a cell 
   **=VLOOKUP("VARCF", 'Valori Indicatori'!$A$2:$D$500, 4, 0)** 
and in excel show N/A but I view the section '**Function arguments**' where the formula show the right result

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY0aY.png, any idea how can fix this?

Comment: It is automatic and circular reference is disable

Comment: If I press Ctrl+Atl+F9 the sheet is recalculated and N/A is replaced with a right value

Comment: How can disable macros?

Answer (score -1):

When you try search with ctf+f on worksheet "Valori Indicatori" could you find value = VARCF?

Comment: Yes, I find value for VARCF in worksheet and if you look in the image I have attached, VARCF has value and that's why I do not understand why in the cell stil appears N / A

Comment: Maybe try to change formatting of these cells to keep it allign.

Comment: Did You found answer of Tour question?

Comment: No, i didn't found answer yet